# Chef client installed on a image, want to have it create its own node

Tags: ruby, powershell, automation, chef-infra

I don't know if this is possible I have only been using chef for about a week and a half now, I can't seem to find anything on the internet about doing this. But basically we have the chef client installed on a image. Each image has a configuration script that is run when the image is setup for the first time to set up the computer name and other settings specific to its setup.

So what I need to have happen once the config script finishes is to have a node created with the node name as the name of the computer that was entered automatically, along with aslo adding it to a role so that these nodes can later be sorted and have the correct roles added. So that going forward each new node will be created as soon as the server is setup without human interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you do this is with the validator key system. Basically in the image have Chef installed, and have the `/etc/chef/client.rb` configuration created and pointed at your Chef Server, but don't create the `client.pem` key. If that key doesn't exist, chef-client will look for a validation key and use that to self-register with the Chef Server (by default it uses the FQDN of the server as the node name, but you can have your last-mile script append `node_name "whatever"` to the `client.rb` if you want to use something else). The difficult bit of validator-based bootstraps is how to store, access, and manage that validator key. The lazy way would be to just include it in the image, but this raises some troubling security issues. Unfortunately the best approach will depend entirely on what kind of systems you are running on and what security infrastructure is available. Also don't forget to remove the validator key after the initial bootstrap, there is a recipe in the `chef-client` cookbook for this.